# awk: warning: escape sequence `\/' treated as plain `/' error when running commands in Mac OSX terminal

Tags: awk

I am currently going through some code meant for a linux system (I am using Mac) and have been trying to run this `awk` line:

```
awk -F"[:,}][^:\/\/]" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/\042'$KEY'\042/)
{print $(i+1)}}}' | tr -d '"' | sed -n ${num}p | sed -e 
's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//' -e 's/[,]*$//'
```

returns the following error:

```
awk: warning: escape sequence `\/' treated as plain `/'.
```

I understand that certain implementations and syntax differ from Mac and Linux. Could this error be one of them? thanks.

Comment: Which characters do you want to use as separators? Why does `\/` occur twice?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: You're asking for help to debug an error message from an awk script so don't post a pipeline with awk+tr+sed+sed scripts, just post THE script thats producing the error message. See [ask] and pay particular attention to creating a [mcve] (emphasis on **Minimal**).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A minimal example:

```
$ awk -F"[:,}][^:\/\/]" '1' /dev/null
awk: warning: escape sequence `\/' treated as plain `/'
```

The fix:

```
$ awk -F'[:,}][^://]' '1' /dev/null
$
```

i.e. there's no reason to escape forward slashes in a dynamic regexp. You have to escape them in a regexp literal (e.g. `/foo\/bar/`) because they're the regexp delimiter, not because they're regexp metachars, and so that's not the case in a dynamic regexp (one that's stored in a string and so delimited by string delimiters, not regexp delimiters). I also fixed your quotes.

Note though that having repetitions of the same character (e.g. `/`) in a bracket expression is not useful. `[/]` is exactly the same set of characters as `[//]` or `[///////]`.

If you did have to escape the `/` then it'd be:

```
$ awk -F'[:,}][^:\\/]' '1' /dev/null
$
```

and if you were using the wrong quotes as in your original code:

```
$ awk -F"[:,}][^:\\\/]" '1' /dev/null
$
```

The 2 escapes are necessary in the `'`-delimited string because awk has to convert the string to a regexp first (parsing pass 1) before using it as a regexp (pass 2).

The 3 escapes are necessary in the `"`-delimited string because in that case you're specifically telling the shell to parse the string so shell has to parse it first (pass 1) before passing it to awk and then awk has to convert the string to a regexp (pass 2) before using it as a regexp (pass 3).

btw the rest of your script is using shell variables incorrectly. This:

```
awk -F'[:,}][^:/]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/\042'$KEY'\042/)
```

IF it was OK to let the shell variable expand to become part of the awk script text (which it is not) would be written as:

```
awk -F'[:,}][^:/]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/\042'"$KEY"'\042/)
```

but the right way to do this is:

```
awk -F'[:,}][^:/]' -v key="$KEY" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~"\042"key"\042")
```

or preferably:

```
awk -F'[:,}][^:/]' -v key="\"$KEY\"" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~key)
```